# trying to config Nginx to load website using ip address

Tags: nginx

So I'm new to Nginx and trying to config it to redirect to ip address of my server.

here is what I'm trying:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name _;

    root /project/public;

    location / {
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

But it's not working. it just load the Nginx welcome page

Comment: You should add more information to your question like which distro you are using, which file did you modify and did you restart `nginx` after you made your changes...?

Comment: @Thomas thanks, I didn't know I should restart it. solved